# Why does sapply() return a list?

Tags: r

I faced up a strange behaviour in [R](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R_%28programming_language%29) with the `sapply()` function. This function is supposed to return a vector, but in the special case where you give it an empty vector, it returns a list.

Correct behaviour with a vector:

```
a = c("A", "B", "C")
a[a == "B"]  # Returns "B"
a[sapply(a, function(x) {x == "B"})] # Returns "B"
```

Correct behaviour with a NULL value:

```
a = NULL
a[a == "B"]  # Returns NULL
a[sapply(a, function(x) {x == "B"})] # Returns NULL
```

Strange behaviour with an empty vector:

```
a = vector()
a[a == "B"]  # Returns NULL
a[sapply(a, function(x) {x == "B"})] # Erreur : type 'list' d'indice incorrect
```

Same error message as with this statement:

```
a[list()] # Erreur dans a[list()] : type 'list' d'indice incorrect
```

Why? Is it a bug?

Due to this strange behaviour, I use `unlist(lapply())`.

Comment: Protip- it's never a bug

Comment: @ChrisBeeley - Never a bug, always a "feature" ;-)  R (and S) have a bunch of less-than-ideal "features" though, and this is one of them. `1:0` is another...

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The real reason for this is that `sapply` doesn't know what your function will return without calling it. In your case the function returns a `logical`, but since `sapply` is given an empty list, the function is never called. Therefore, it has to come up with a type and it defaults to `list`.

...For this very reason (and for performance), `vapply` was introduced! It requires you to specify the return value type (and length). This allows it to do the right thing. As a bonus, it is also faster!

```
sapply(LETTERS[1:3], function(x) {x == "B"}) # F, T, F
sapply(LETTERS[0], function(x) {x == "B"})   # list()

vapply(LETTERS[1:3], function(x) {x == "B"}, logical(1)) # F, T, F
vapply(LETTERS[0], function(x) {x == "B"}, logical(1))   # logical()
```

See `?vapply` for more info.

Answer (score 7):

The help for the function `?sapply` has this in the **Value** section

```
For ‘sapply(simplify = TRUE)’ and ‘replicate(simplify = TRUE)’: if
‘X’ has length zero or ‘n = 0’, an empty list.
```

In both your cases:

```
> length(NULL)
[1] 0
> length(vector())
[1] 0
```

Hence `sapply()` returns:

```
> sapply(vector(), function(x) {x == "B"})
list()
> sapply(NULL, function(x) {x == "B"})
list()
```

Your error is not from `sapply()` but from `[` as this shows:

```
> a[list()]
Error in a[list()] : invalid subscript type 'list'
```

So the issue is related to how subsetting of `NULL` and an empty vector (`vector()`) is performed. Nothing to do with `sapply()` at all. In both cases it returns consistent output, an empty list.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, they both return a `list`. The only difference between the two is the when you try to index `NULL` it always returns NULL (even if your index was a list), but when you try to index an empty vector, it checks the index, and realizes it is a `list`.

```
a = NULL
res = sapply(a, function(x) x == "B") # Res is an empty list
a[res] # returns NULL, because any index of NULL is NULL.


a = vector()
res = sapply(a, function(x) x == "B") # Still an empty list.
a[res] # but you can't index a vector with a list!
```