# Using vapply and mutate in R to apply function to a column in dataframe

Tags: r, dplyr

I have the following function:

```
scaling_function<-function(p,a,b,c,d){
  return(c+(d-c)/(b-a)*(p-a))
}
```

I define another based on this function as:

```
score_function<-function(x){
  if(x%>>%4 & x%<=%5){
    scaling_function(x,5,4,0,2)
  }else if(x%>>%3 & x%<=%4){
    scaling_function(x,4,3,3,2)
  }else if(x%>>%2 & x%<=%3){
    scaling_function(x,3,2,4,3)
  }else if(x%>=%1 & x%<=%2){
    scaling_function(x,2,1,5,4)
  }
}
```

I would like to apply this function to a column in a dataframe using mutate, for example

```
df<-df0%>%
group_by(col)%>%
summarise(
average=mean(col2)
)%>%
mutate(
    score=vapply(average, score_function, FUN.VALUE = c(double)),
)
```

I was originally using sapply, which is working for all of my other functions, but vapply is returning a list for this function instead of a dataframe column. I found this page:

[Why does sapply() return a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9668456/why-does-sapply-return-a-list)

This seems to answer my question but I cannot get it to work. I keep getting the error

```
Error in `mutate_cols()`:
! Problem with `mutate()` column `average`.
i `score = vapply(average, score_function, FUN.VALUE = c(double))`.
x values must be type 'list',
 but FUN(X[[1]]) result is type 'double'
```

How can I make this work?

Comment: What about `double(1)` instead of `c(double)`?

Comment: Can’t you use `case_when()` instead of your `score_function()` so you wouldn’t need `vapply()` in the first place.

Comment: In what package can we find `%>>%` and `%<=%`?

Comment: @RuiBarradas fpCompare